# Thumbprint::Initialize: Failed to parse ‎9CD9F80CB5B0FB999

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to enable Https in my local Service Fabric cluster and I keep getting the following error:

Thumbprint::Initialize: Failed to parse ‎‎9CD9F80CB5B0FB9995D1444E3DEDAE211B732B7E as certificate thumbprint, the format should be '2855e9bbedc65d3dc82c7335d1ec074586b09006' or '28 55 e9 bb ed c6 5d 3d c8 2c 73 35 d1 ec 07 45 86 b0 90 06'

I typed the thumbprint manually without any copy pasting, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I typed the entire thumbprint manually without putting any spaces between. Then it started working.